# Classic ASP / VbScript - SAML 2.0 - Identity provider

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, saml

I have a Classic ASP / VbScript website that I need to act as an SAML 2.0 Identitiy Provider.

Despite extensive searching I have been unable to find any resource / demo / example to steer me towards a solution.

As I can't find any information I am thinking that it is simply not possible, or is it so obvious nobody needs to ask or that is such an uncommon situation that no resource exists.

**Further clarification added**

My website.com is coded in Classic ASP / VbScript running in IIS7.5 on Windows 2008 server.

User logs into website.com and can now browse the site.

One section of website.com has links to other-website.com which ordinarily requires login.

To avoid this I can use SAML 2 based SSO to gain direct access to other-website.com by passing over EntityID and unique references from website.com database which correspond to other-website.com database to ensure authentication.

What I really don't understand is from the point that the User clicks hyperlink to other-website.com what I need to do to create and pass over the required information to other-website.com

I think that I have to create some form of encrypted XML document and then POST it via a form to the URL supplied by other-website.com - but I am not sure how to do this and can't find any sample / demo to help.

Hopefully that explains fully what I am trying to achieve!

Comment: This would be funny if it weren't appalling. Adding a jet engine to a horse-drawn wagon. @Ian's answer below makes good sense: ship the wagon on a jet plane.

Comment: John, could you explain your comment?  Sounds like you are saying that because the site is in Classic ASP I should not be using SSO? Or have I missed your point?

Comment: Because the site is in Classic ASP, you should preferably scrap it, but if you can't scrap it, then you should change it the least amount possible, as suggested by @Ian, below.

Comment: This would be funny if it weren't appalling :) Replacing an entire site with one written in another language, that has the same look, functionality, performance and security - just to facilitate SSO to A.N.Other website. Now, your suggestion may not be appalling if you can explain either why using SSO from a Classic ASP site is simply not possible, or explain the steps that I would need to take to make it work - which by the sounds of it are more cumbersome than re-writing the entire site in, presumably, .NET ??

Answer (score 1):

The normal model is that you have a third-party product (ADFS, OpenAM, PingIdentity, ...) as your IP and your application is the RP (Relying Party).

You don't normally have an application as an IP.

What do you intend to authenticate against?

ADFS / WIF is based around ASP.NET not ASP.

WIF uses WS-Federation not SAML.

To use SAML you need ADFS and that runs on Windows Server.

Answer (score 1):

Check out PingFederate and the Agentless Integration Kit from PingIdentity. Here's an overview of how the integration would work with your application - http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/AIK12/Implementing+IdP+Functionality. PF would handle all the fancy standards-based requirements and your application would continue to maintain its own session and user authentication functionality. When SSO is needed, you then invoke the PF server. Once you integrate your app, it's very simple to add new service providers via the PF Admin Console.

[Note: I work for Ping]

Comment: two questions - what is the cost?

And second - and I am probably being dense here - but Step 1 says "PingFederate receives an authentication request for a SAML assertion." - that sounds an awful lot like the process I need to do, which I don't understand - from my comment above; "What I really don't understand is from the point that the User clicks hyperlink to other-website.com what I need to do to create and pass over the required information to other-website.com"

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't really comment on cost. I'd recommend requesting a free trial license. That'll allow our team to help determine use cases. We can also get a Solutions Architect engaged to get through the technical details. Ping has a number of customers with Classic ASP apps so this is definitely something Ping can help you solve.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this question, I would highly recomend taking a look at this article and sample code,  I was in the same situation as the OP and found for me it was easier to use this C# ASP.Net code as a starting point (I have little experiance of C# but still got this working quickly and easily).  It's clearly comented and works right out of the box and was easy to amend for my needs.  In the end it was simpler to implement this in .NET and call it from my ASP application than create from scratch in ASP.

http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2008/09/single-signon-with-saml/

Comment: That link doesn't go anywhere. And I really need that solution! Do you have another copy of it I can obtain somewhere?

Comment: Try this?  https://web.archive.org/web/20161028031810/http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2008/09/single-signon-with-saml/